# Custom Error Pages not working correctly in .NET

Tags: .net, web-config, custom-error-pages

i have the following piece of code my my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Exception.aspx" enableVersionHeader="false">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
```

so, as far as i understand it should be redirecting me to an Exception.aspx page whenever there's an error
however, when i try to test this by putting in some bad parameters in the url, i get the following message:

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

did i miss something? i thought it would redirect me to the error page i created?

Comment: Can you disable the redirect to post the error message (with stack)? There are many reasons it may not work. For example because of errors inside the Errors.aspx page.

Comment: Did you check by providing the absolute path of the error page (eg: `http://localhost/Exception.aspx`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong with the config and I had to delete and retype the statement to get it to work. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the mode to ="Off" it should redirect correctly.

Comment: I'm not positive on that.  I see mine and I have it set to off, that said, I have a bunch of complicated pipeline stuff going on too.